# Change the tag-it font size

Tags: tag-it

Does anybody know how to change the size of the fonts appearing in tags of the tag-it plug in? I went over the stylesheet but it does not seam obvious to me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the color specifc css file, tagit-stylish-yellow.css for example.

Look for

```
ul.tagit { cursor: text; font-size: 14px; color: #333; }
```

and change the font-size.

I found this by going to the demo site in Chrome, start the inspector by pressing F12, selecting the tag and looking at the css directives that affect it.